# How do I call a function *after* my ajax call functions complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm using jQuery to run some ajax:

```
var stuff = {};

function do_stuff(thing){
    stuff[thing.id] = thing;
}

function fun(){
    var calls = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var call = $.get(URL, function(data){
             do_stuff(data);
        });
        calls.push(call);
    }

    $.when(calls).done(function(){
        console.log(stuff);
    });
}
```

I'm using `$.when`, but what I get is `{}` instead of the data that I expect. When I set a breakpoint in Chrome, the `log` line gets called before any of the `do_stuff` calls - so apparently the order of the calls get mixed up. Is there a way I can ensure the `console.log(stuff)` line gets called *after* my get callbacks do?

Comment: Have you tried using chaining? `call = $.get(URL).then(do_stuff);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on deferred objects: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

You're correct in using `$.when`, but that accepts arguments of deferred objects. So in reality you need something like `$.when(calls[0], calls[1], ...)`. This is kind of cumbersome, so luckily can use the javascript function `.apply` and get something like:

```
$.when.apply(null, calls).done(function() {
    console.log(stuff);
}
```